# How to get Intellij to auto import Spark SQL Functions

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

When writing Spark Scala code in Intellij, I have to manually Spark SQL functions, like `col` or `lit` (https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html). Is there a way to get IntelliJ to auto import them for me? All other Spark API's (Datasets, Rows, etc) work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto import does not work for methods. `col` or `lit` are methods and not objects/classes like `Datasets`/`Rows`.

Auto-import will work if you write `functions.col` or `functions.lit` instead.